How do I provide exceptions for a GPL3+ game engine?
I'm planning on a game engine project, and I'm looking to use the GPLv3+ to protect the project. The engine will have a scripting language integrated and an editor, so people can make their games and write its logic and for people to play said games the engine will export the project with a copy of itself minus the editor and debugging parts.
I have two concerns, however:

The project (the game, not the engine) and the scripts (written in the custom scripting language of the engine, for the logic of the game) of a developer would have to be GPLv3+ because the binary is shipped with the project to allow players to play said game?

If a developer wants to build a game using the API offered by the game engine (not relying on the editor or the scripting language for the logic), compiles and distribute the final binary, he has to put the source code using the API under the GPLv3+ too?


I would like to protect the game engine source code using the GPLv3+ but I would also like for developers to license the final product (their game) as they see fit, but I don't know if my project can provide an exception (if that's even needed) and if so, how?

Are the scripts/project system of your engine different from the API? I.e. are 1 and 2 different points? You might need two exceptions. Or you might need LGPL for point 2 (the API) and a custom exception for point 1 (i.e. the scripts needn't be GPL).

@Brandin I don't believe they are different, I see them as being one except that the custom scripting language is basically a binding/wrapper around the API that a developer would use to make his game if he happens to make it in the same programming language as the game engine was built with.

You say in your Q, that to play the game, the engine "will export the project with a copy of itself minus the editor and debugging parts". Have you considered making that part ("the copy of itself minus editor and debugging") of your project an LGPL-licensed piece, and then make the rest of it (i.e. the editor and debugger) GPL-only? A company shipping a commercial game would then only have to distribute the LGPL part, and I think it's pretty clearly understood how that works.

@Brandin I'm not really sure how that would work because as I see it, such a binary would be produced from the same source code of the game engine.

@shackra: How about having the game engine produce a batch file or shell script which e.g. launches an unmodified copy of the main game engine, passing it a path to the game data file?  Any GPL obligations associated with the game engine could be taken care of by bundling its source code, but I don't think any country's copyright laws would view shell script of the form #!superGameEngine awesomeGameFile.sgedat as being a "derivative work" of superGameEngine.

The GPL FAQ provides a solution for your exact problem:

How can I allow linking of proprietary modules with my GPL-covered library under a controlled interface only?
Add this text to the license notice of each file in the
package, at the end of the text that says the file is distributed
under the GNU GPL.  .....
This exception enables linking with differently licensed modules over
the specified interface (“ABCDEF”), while ensuring that users would
still receive source code as they normally would under the GPL.
Only the copyright holders for the program can legally authorize this
exception. If you wrote the whole program yourself, then assuming your
employer or school does not claim the copyright, you are the copyright
holder—so you can authorize the exception. But if you want to use
parts of other GPL-covered programs by other authors in your code, you
cannot authorize the exception for them. You have to get the approval
of the copyright holders of those programs.

The full text of the GPL-3.0 Interface Exception (with SPDX identifier GPL-3.0-interface-exception):

Linking [name of library] statically or dynamically with other
modules is making a combined work based on [name of library]. Thus,
the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public License cover the
whole combination.
As a special exception, the copyright holders of [name of library]
give you permission to combine [name of library] program with free
software programs or libraries that are released under the GNU LGPL
and with independent modules that communicate with [name of library]
solely through the [name of library's interface] interface. You may
copy and distribute such a system following the terms of the GNU GPL
for [name of library] and the licenses of the other code concerned,
provided that you include the source code of that other code when and
as the GNU GPL requires distribution of source code and provided that
you do not modify the [name of library's interface] interface.
Note that people who make modified versions of [name of library] are
not obligated to grant this special exception for their modified
versions; it is their choice whether to do so. The GNU General Public
License gives permission to release a modified version without this
exception; this exception also makes it possible to release a modified
version which carries forward this exception. If you modify the [name
of library's interface] interface, this exception does not apply to
your modified version of [name of library], and you must remove this
exception when you distribute your modified version.
This exception is an additional permission under section 7 of the GNU
General Public License, version 3 ("GPLv3")

The full SPDX license identifier will then be:
SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later WITH GPL-3.0-interface-exception


Would this language really work for the game scripting case? The way I imagine the OP question, the game engine is going to be GPL3+, but the script files might not be. So, it seems like you're hoping that someone reading the above is going to translate "script files" into "library" and "interface" when reading it, but this kind of translation does not seem obvious to me. Why not explicitly say in the exception that the license of the software does not cover the script files, that it does not cover the graphics, sounds files, etc. Similar to the Linux syscall exception?

@Brandin: Modifying the license text makes it incompatible with GPL-3.0-interface-exception. But the game engine author can unilaterally declare that their API is an API as intended by the GPL interface exception.

@MSalters I guess my comment was more like "why use the interface exception for this"? The language here might do what OP intended, but it looks like it will make the game developers jump through technical hoops to do so. I.e., you'd have to first make an interface to the engine and package it as a library, and then make that library LGPL. Then include that LGPL library in your commercial game. Yes, it's possible, but I think the OP just wants to clarify that using the supplied scripting interface and engine does not constitute a derived work. i.e. similar to the Linux syscall exception.

I'm accepting this as the answer. It seems that basically I need to define the API of the engine in case someone wants to make a game using C++ directly. Since the custom scripting language of the game engine editor is basically a wrapper/binding to that API it should be obvious that nothing written with such a custom scripting language is a derivate work that should use the same license as the game engine.

@shackra Why don't you apply "GPL-3.0-or-later WITH GPL-3.0-interface-exception"  to the game's scripting language too? Or alternatively, you can use the Classpath Exception that OpenJDK uses. However, the language used in the Classpath Exception is very similar to the GPL-3.0 interface exception anyway.

@shackra You can also consider a weak copyleft license for the scripting language e.g. Mozilla Public License v2.0, which is a file-level copyleft license.

The obvious problem with this exception is that it is de facto incompatible with any model that does not involve a CLA. If a contributor decides to add a new function to the interface, then they are prohibited from expanding the exception to that function, and nobody else can authorize it either (because nobody else holds the copyright to that new function). The only workaround is a CLA. I really wish the FSF would say that explicitly in their FAQ.

The basic rule is that a kernel or virtual machine can be covered by the GPL and still run non-GPL programs. For example, Linux states that making syscalls is using Linux in the intended way and does not cause the program to become GPL as well. The same applies to OpenJDK, and the same applies to your engine.
Your case is apparently an exception because the scripts and assets are bundled with the engine into a single executable. The easiest solution is to just not do this - bundle those in an archive file. Again, this is standard practice.

For me, the problem is your first and second sentences rather undermine each other.  If it were the "rule [...] that a kernel or virtual machine can be covered by the GPL and still run non-GPL programs", the kernel wouldn't need to state that exception.  I'm not saying there aren't useful rules and guidelines in this field, but I'm not sure you've put your finger on them.

@MadHatter: I think you're making a common mistake here. You're confusing "making an specific exception to a general rule"  with "explanation how a general rule applies to a specific case". The GPL is a general-purpose license and has no concept of "syscalls". Linux needs to define that its syscalls are its normal API.

If the general rule doesn't apply to the specific case, no exception is required; that's pretty much logically unavoidable.  In the case of Linux, the exception for syscalls exists because the developers believe that otherwise, programs making syscalls would be derivative works, and subject to the GPL.  The existence of the exception demonstrates a belief that that rule would otherwise apply in this case, not that it wouldn't.

@MadHatter: That's my point. An exception means that the general rule would otherwise apply. A clarification means that the general rule didn't apply in the first place. There is "GPL with exception" in the Linux kernel, e.g. GPL-2.0+ WITH GCC-exception-2.0 but the syscall API falls under GPL-2.0+ WITH Linux-syscall-note.  This demonstrates the difference between exceptions and clarifications.

OpenJDK uses the Classpath Exception.

The kernel itself describes the syscall exception as an exception: "The Linux Kernel is provided under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only [...] with an explicit syscall exception described in LICENSES/exceptions/Linux-syscall-note" (from eg here, the bold text is mine).  You may feel it's a mere clarification, but I don't find that persuasive.

@MadHatter The wording in your example does seem like it is an exception, but reading that file it is worded like this: <<NOTE! This copyright does not cover user programs that use kernel
services by normal system calls - this is merely considered normal use of the kernel, and does not fall under the heading of "derived work".>> So it says it's not considered a derivative, not that it is considered derivative but the copyleft doesn't apply.

Indeed, but I've always read this as the developers clarifying their position (we don't regard use of these syscalls as creating a copyright derivative, and we undertake not to enforce against it) not the law's (we believe that copyright law doesn't affect the use of syscalls).  Given that they clearly regard it as an exception, I'm minded to continue thinking this way.
